# Is there a way to explore my WHS files via Xbox 360's Media Center app?

Tags: streaming, windows-home-server, xbox360, media-center-extender

I know its a "Console" question but its really more of a **Media Center Extender** question!

I can access the data through the Video/Pictures options, but not through the Media Center App.

Also I can only see the videos that are directly on the Videos folder on my WHS, but not any of the subfolders.  Same thing in my Laptop, if I connect to my WHS through Media Player it will only show the videos on Videos but not any other sub-folder, but if I open Media Center I can then connect to server and see all the folders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont think you can install Windows Media Center on WHS, which you would need to do to be able to connect it to the 360.

But, you can use Media Center on your laptop and extend that to the 360. Then to access the data from your WHS just add the relevant folders from WHS in Media Center as shown in the picture.

[image]

Regards to the Video folder, I dont really understand why it has this behavior, so I cant help you here.

Hope that helps.

---

(...ctd from below) You could try [Vuze](http://www.vuze.com/) (Yes, I know its also a bittorent client, but its the only program I am aware of that converts files so easily)  which automatically [converts videos](http://www.vuze.com/devices/) so they are playable on multiple devices, incl the Xbox 360. Once you add them to Vuze, it will detect the device you want it to play on and start to convert them to a playable format. Once they are done, they are accessible on the Xbox for watching. This isnt ideal though as it means converting every video file that isnt comaptible, and it means not using Media Center which kinda defeats the object.

Comment: Thanks... thats sort of what I ended up doing, but its still not the nicests thing.. the whole point was being able to watch my shows straight from the xbox, and not having to use my laptop (I used to have to plug my laptop to my tv)... however it turns out must of the videos I have can be played on windows but not on my xbox... :(

Comment: Yeah, its not the most efficient method. I wish they would update WHS (which still runs on Windows Server 2003) to something more modern and include the newer features such as Media Center. Its a shame the Xbox has such bad video codec support. Surely, as they are both made by Microsoft, they should support the same codecs so if it can be played on Windows it would play on the Xbox. (...continued in original question)

Comment: Thanks, i guess its easier just to keep using my laptop directly with the tv... at least i can stream my files to my laptop from the WHS..